# ogr2ogr - extracting S-57 layers

Tags: shapefile, layers, ogr2ogr

I'm trying to extract the layer DEPARE from an S-57 datafile and convert it into a shapefile. I'm using ogr2ogr from OpenGeo Suite 4.5 (GDAL 1.11.1) on Windows 7 64 bit.

The problem is that when I issue `ogr2ogr -f "ESRI shapefile" depare.shp US6RI26M.000 DEPARE` I get an error `FAILURE: Couldn't fetch requested layer 'DEPARE'!`.

This seems odd because when I load the same s-57 file into QGis I can choose the layer DEPARE among all other layers. I've tried calling `ogrinfo -ro -summary US6RI26M.000` which returns the follwing:

```
INFO: Open of `US6RI26M.000'
      using driver `S57' successful.
1: DSID (None)
2: Point (Point)
3: Line (Line String)
4: Area (Polygon)
5: Meta (None)
```

I struggle to understand why I don't see the same layers that I get when opening the file in QGis - DISD, BRIDGE, BUISGL, BUAARE, CTNARE, DEPARE... Is the DEPARE layer part of a higher-level layer `4: Area (Polygon)` as shown by ogrinfo?

**Question: How can I extract the DEPARE layer from an S-57 file and convert it into a shapefile using the ogr2ogr tool?**

I'm clearly missing something. I've searched for related q&a but none I've found so far solves my problem.

Comment: Which GDAL version that might be? The driver info is different from the example at http://mapserver.org/fr/input/vector/S57.html which shows the driver name as `using driver IHO S-57 (ENC) successful`

Comment: I'm using GDAL 1.11.1, released 2014/09/24 (updated above).

Comment: You may have a OSGeo4W shell on your computer. Try from that or download Windows binaries from gisinternals.com/sdk.

Comment: It does indeed work using OSGeo4W shell! Will you please shed a bit of light on why that is?

Comment: The GDAL in OpenGeo Suite must have been compiled somehow differently than the OSGeo4W version. Perhaps with older source code for the driver or libraries that S-57 driver depends. Because of the different name of the driver in your ogr2ogr example I guess that GDAL in OpenGeo Suite builds with some old version of the S-57 driver. Write a message to Boundless and ask.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. I've compiled GDAL/OGR 2.0.0 on both Linux and Windows (VS2012). Both when using the ogrinfo utility and when accessing the file in my own program using the GDAL/OGR library I get the expected layers on Linux (M_COVR, DEPARE and so on) while on Windows I get the exact same list as in the question. Did you ever figure out what was going on here?

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer on the [gdal-dev mailing list](http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/gdal-dev/2009-September/022055.html).

In summary, there are some .csv-files needed by the S-57 (ENC) reader. These are by default put in the GDAL_HOME/data directory (at least in GDAL 2.0.0), so for using ogrinfo you first need to do `SET S57_CSV=C:\gdal\install\dir\data`, then everything (both ogrinfo and your own programs) should be able to read ENC files correctly.

This is also documented on the [S-57 driver page](http://www.gdal.org/drv_s57.html).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you haven't set your system variables for GDAL.  If you do the following:

```
GDAL_DATA=C:\PATH\TO\gdal\bin\gdal-data
GDAL_DRIVER_PATH=C:\PATH\TO\gdal\bin\gdal\plugins
```

With the important one being the **GDAL_DATA** path

It happens on about every machine of mine when I load S57 data